# I need to get only the next sequence of variable in timestamp format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

```
#count    ,date
98.000000, 2014-03-16

267.000000, 2014-03-23

298.000000, 2014-03-30

313.000000, 2014-04-06

225.000000, 2014-04-13

226.000000 2014-04-20
```

I have two variables: one is count and other is date time with week sequence in it.

When I concatenate the first variable with some values, I need to fill the date time variable by their sequence in the DataFrame.

Comment: Have you tried some code so far?

Comment: yes i have tried by making the date variable as index and did the concatenation but it didnt give the output which i expected....

Comment: Maybe you can post some code so we can help better?

Comment: df.set_index('date',drop=True,inplace=True) ; df2 = pd.DataFrame(); df2['Count'] = [50]; dat = pd.concat((df,df2),axis=0)

Comment: Can you post an expected input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("ex1.csv",
                names=['count', 'date'],
                index_col='date')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(); 
df2['count'] = [50]; 
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.values[len(df)-1]) + (     datetime.datetime.strptime(df.index.values[len(df)-1], "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.datetime.strptime(df.index.values[len(df)-2], "%Y-%m-%d"))
df2.set_index('date',inplace=True) 
dat = pd.concat((df,df2))
print(dat)
```

Comment: its working...but i need to add multiple values in count variable

Comment: i had a issue wen i had a data with month level. Ex: im having the last value i.e nthindex in date format as 2018-07-01 and n-1th index as 2018-06-01 so the difference is 30 days and as per code im getting date as 2018-07-31. but i need the value as 2018-08-01. can u please sort out this issue

Comment: The logic here is looking previous data as 7 days, If data range changes then you need to write accordingly. 

if weeks use following 
    df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.values[len(df)-1]) + pd.DateOffset(weeks=1) 

if months use following 
    df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.values[len(df)-1]) + pd.DateOffset(months=1)